# MySQL update set join and user join

Tags: mysql

hi I need help with this judgment MySQL

```
UPDATE
  table1
SET
  table1.campo1= '1'
FROM
  table1
INNER JOIN
  tabala2 ON tabale1.campo2 = table2.campo1
WHERE
  table1.campo3 = table2.campo2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update don't use from  .. the table and the join first . then the set and last the where clause

```
UPDATE table1 
INNER JOIN tabala2 ON tabale1.campo2 = table2.campo1
SET table1.campo1= '1' 
WHERE table1.campo3 = table2.campo2
```

Comment: thanks, I know I am a newbie on this but you saved me from a big problem

Comment: well, I'm happy.. If my answer is right. please mark it as accepted ..